# Connecting Keybed to Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, teensy

I learned some basic Arduino stuff in school but we never really got to the point of reading proper schematics. I was just trying to figure out how to connect this Fatar Keybed I bought to my microcontroller (teensy) to convert the signals it sends to MIDI data + perform "matrix scanning"

[image: Fatar Keybed Schematic]

There's only four female ports for connecting the wires on the keybed. Does anyone here know how I would figure out which to connect to which pin on my microcontroller?

[image: Fatar Ports]

Answer (score 0):

The pins depend on what pins the software does matrix scanning. If you don't have any software yet, you can decide to map them in any way you want to free pins that are not reserved for another use.